# ¿Cómo leer un JSON dentro de un array [] Node JS? / [object Object]

Tags: javascript, nodejs, json

Estoy trabajando con Node JS.

Necesito recorrer la info que me devuelve la data y almacenar ciertos datos en variables que luego le pasaré a un objeto para enviarlos en un `insert` hacia una tabla de gestión.

Hago una consulta cuando el código de tarifa es ingresado por el usuario es igual al que esta en una determinada tabla denominada (.tbl_ptar) de esta forma ↓

```javascript
let consultaTarifa = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM '+bdd_name+'.tbl_ptar WHERE COD_TARIFA = "' + [codigo_tarifa] + '";');
```

Al validar por consola lo que me devuelve tengo este resultado ↓

```
console.log(consultaTarifa);
```

↓↓ Retorna esto ↓↓

```
[
  RowDataPacket {
    PK_ID_COD_PTAR: 1,
    FK_COD_FUENTE: 1,
    NOMBRE_PTAR: '711',
    NOM_COD_TARIFA: 'Triple Digital Plus 100 MB',
    COD_TARIFA: 'UNM1',
    VALOR_TARIFA: '99900',
    COD_VELOCIDAD: 'CMB',
    TECNOLOGIA: 'HFC',
    FECHA_REGISTRO: null,
    FECHA_MODIFICACION: null,
    DESCRIPCION_PTAR: 'PTAR 711 - TRIPLE PLAY 100 MB - ESTRATOS 1 Y 2',
    ESTADO: 'Activa'
  }
]
```

Al codificar esta línea puedo observar la data en el navegador de la siguiente forma ↓

```
let consultaTarifaResultado = await res.json(consultaTarifa);
```

Resultado navegador ↓

> [{"PK_ID_COD_PTAR":1,"FK_COD_FUENTE":1,"NOMBRE_PTAR":"711","NOM_COD_TARIFA":"Triple
> Digital Plus 100
> MB","COD_TARIFA":"UNM1","VALOR_TARIFA":"99900","COD_VELOCIDAD":"CMB","TECNOLOGIA":"HFC","FECHA_REGISTRO":null,"FECHA_MODIFICACION":null,"DESCRIPCION_PTAR":"PTAR
> 711 - TRIPLE PLAY 100 MB - ESTRATOS 1 Y 2","ESTADO":"Activa"}

Al enviar luego por consola la variable *consultaTarifaResultado*

```
console.log("Probando json >>>> "+consultaTarifaResultado);
```

me arroja lo siguiente ↓

```sh
Probando json >>>> [object Object]
```

***Qué necesito***

Poder almacenar esto

```
    [
      RowDataPacket {
        PK_ID_COD_PTAR: 1,
        FK_COD_FUENTE: 1,
        NOMBRE_PTAR: '711',
        NOM_COD_TARIFA: 'Triple Digital Plus 100 MB',
        COD_TARIFA: 'UNM1',
        VALOR_TARIFA: '99900',
        COD_VELOCIDAD: 'CMB',
        TECNOLOGIA: 'HFC',
        FECHA_REGISTRO: null,
        FECHA_MODIFICACION: null,
        DESCRIPCION_PTAR: 'PTAR 711 - TRIPLE PLAY 100 MB - ESTRATOS 1 Y 2',
        ESTADO: 'Activa'
      }
    ]
```

dentro de variables separadas, es decir algo así ↓

```
 const codigo_tarifa_aplicada = NOM_COD_TARIFA / el dato de la consulta por separado → → (Triple Digital Plus 100 MB); como lo hago con la data interna que relaciono a continuacion ↓

//Data Interna Usuario
  const documento_responsable_gestion = req.user.USU_CNOMBRES_APELLIDOS;
  const responsable_gestion = req.user.USU_CNOMBRES_APELLIDOS;
  const loginCMS = req.user.USU_CLOGINCMS;
  const usuario_red = req.user.USU_CUSUARIO;
  const area_gestion = req.user.USU_CAREA_GESTION;
  const rol = req.user.USU_CROL;
```

Poder pasar los datos que me devuelve la consulta a cada una de estas variables como lo hago con la data de logeo interna o similar, mejor dicho: poder alcanzar los datos en vez de obtener un `[object Object]`

```
  //Data Interna Listado Ptars
  const id_codigo_ptar_aplicada = "codigo_tarifa_consultado";
  //console.log(id_codigo_ptar_aplicada);
  /* const codigo_tarifa_aplicada = req.codigo_tarifa_consultado.TECNOLOGIA;
  const codigo_nombre_ptar_aplicada = req.codigo_tarifa_consultado.NOMBRE_PTAR;
  const valor_tarifa_aplicada = req.codigo_tarifa_consultado.VALOR_TARIFA;
  const codigo_velocidad_aplicada = req.codigo_tarifa_consultado.COD_VELOCIDAD; */
  const estado_inicial_solicitud = "Pendiente";
```

Luego las paso al objeto que seguidamente envío al INSERT ↓

```
  const nuevoRegistro = {
    FK_ID_COD_PTAR: id_codigo_ptar_aplicada,
    CEDULA_USER: documento_responsable_gestion,
    RESPONSABLE_USER: responsable_gestion,
    LOGINCMS_USER: loginCMS,
    USUARIO_RED: usuario_red,
    AREA_GESTION_USER: area_gestion,
    ROL_USER: rol,
    CUENTA_RR: cuentaRR,
    /* TECNOLOGIA: codigo_tarifa_aplicada,
    PTAR_APLICADA_USER: codigo_nombre_ptar_aplicada,
    COD_TARIFA: codigo_tarifa,
    VALOR_TARIFA: valor_tarifa_aplicada,
    COD_VELOCIDAD: codigo_velocidad_aplicada,*/
    BOT_ESTADO_GESTION: estado_inicial_solicitud
  };
```

Comment: que arroja si solo pones `console.log(consultaTarifaResultado);`?

Comment: [_No uses `console.log(obj)`, usá `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)))`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/log#logging_objects). Paseitos por la documentación vienen bien de vez en cuando :) (Nota: va para el OP, je)

Comment: Pipe

Al enviar luego por consola la variable consultaTarifaResultado

console.log("Probando json >>>> "+consultaTarifaResultado);
me arroja lo siguiente ↓

Probando json >>>> [object Object]

Comment: let consultaTarifa = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM '+bdd_name+'.tbl_ptar WHERE COD_TARIFA = "' + [codigo_tarifa] + '";');
    console.log(consultaTarifa);
    console.log("Probando acceso a objeto >>> "+Object[0]);

    console.log("Parseo >>>> "+JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(consultaTarifa)))






Probando acceso a objeto >>> undefined
Parseo >>>> [object Object]
consultaTarifa= undefined

Answer (score 1):

**Ya logre sacar el problema**

Les comparto la solucion para estos casos.

```js
Yo tenia la busqueda así ↓

//Busco  código de la tarifa a aplicar en la tabla ptar
  let consultaTarifa = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM '+bdd_name+'.tbl_ptar WHERE COD_TARIFA = "' + [codigo_tarifa] + '";'); //Areglo
  console.log(consultaTarifa);

//El console retorna algo así ↓

[
  RowDataPacket {
    PK_ID_COD_PTAR: 1,
    FK_COD_FUENTE: 1,
    NOMBRE_PTAR: '711',
    DESCRIPCION_PTAR: 'PTAR 711 - TRIPLE PLAY 100 MB - ESTRATOS 1 Y 2',
    NOM_COD_TARIFA: 'Triple Digital Plus 100 MB',
    COD_TARIFA: 'UNM1',
    VALOR_TARIFA: '99900',
    COD_VELOCIDAD: 'CMB',
    TECNOLOGIA: 'HFC',
    ESTADO: 'Activa',
    CARGO_RESPONSABLE: null,
    RESPONSABLE_GESTION: null,
    FECHA_REGISTRO: null,
    FECHA_MODIFICACION: null
  }
]


//Para acceder a los elmentos y valores debo primero decodificar con .stringify y a su vez con .parse de esta forma ↓↓

//Decodifico y Parseo la consulta
  let resultadoConsultaTarifa = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(consultaTarifa[0]));

//Seguido a esto ya puedo acceder al valor de esta forma ↓↓
resultadoConsultaTarifa.NOM_COD_TARIFA

//↑ Esto al imprimirlo dentro de un console.log me retorma algo como esto ↓

console.log(resultadoConsultaTarifa.NOM_COD_TARIFA);

//En consola obtengo → Triple Digital Plus 100 MB

♦ Con esto ya puedo acceder a cualquier elemento y guardarlo en una variable o directamente en el objeto para hacer luego el insert.

Espero les sirva mi solución o si alguno se anima a dar otro tipo de solución quedo antento para aprender más.
```

Comment: Creo que es lo que te recomendaron hacer en los comentarios, una mención al que te la recomendó no vendría mal, recuerda que lo cortés no quita lo valiente ;)